# Can ordinal arithmetic prove 1+1=2?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

In Jech's *Set Theory* he defines $$0=\emptyset,\quad 1=\{0\},\quad 2=\{0,1\}$$  The definition of sum on ordinals is $$\alpha+0=\alpha,\quad \alpha+(\beta+1)=(\alpha+\beta)+1,\quad \alpha+\beta = \lim_{\xi\rightarrow\beta}(\alpha+\xi)$$

where the last equation is for $\beta>0$.  The limit of an non-decreasing sequence $\langle a_\xi : \xi <\alpha\rangle$ is defined as $\sup\{a_\xi:\xi<\alpha\}$.

How could this setup show that $1+1=2$?  We would need to show $$2=\sup\{1+\xi:\xi < 1\}$$ but how do we compare 2 to an arbitrary $1+\xi$ when it begs the question of how we identify $1+\xi$?

Comment: Page $20$ (at least in my edition), immediately below fact $(2.5)$ following **Lemma** $\mathbf{2.11}$: ‘We thus define $\alpha+1=\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$ (the *successor* of $\alpha$)’.

Comment: The equation $\alpha+\beta = \lim_{\xi\rightarrow\beta}(\alpha+\xi)$ is for $\beta$ a limit ordinal, not for all $\beta\gt 0.$ So applying this part of the definition to compute $1+1$ is incorrect, because $1$ is not a limit ordinal.

Comment: I prefer the following def'n of $a+b$ for all ordinal $a,b:$ ..... $a+b$ is the  unique ordinal that is order-isomorphic to the lexicographic order  on $(\{0\}\times a)\cup (\{1\}\times b). $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall the definition
$\alpha + 1 = S(\alpha)$.
So
$$1+1 = S(1) = 1 \cup \{1\} = \{0\} \cup \{1\} = \{0,1\}=2.$$

Comment: Does this then mean that $\alpha+1$ has multiple definitions? Because I was assuming I shouldn't use the old definition in this context if this one is distinct from it. Or perhaps this new definition should only hold for $\alpha\ne 0,1$?

Comment: Actually, the sum of ordinals is the typical example of transfinite recursive definition.

Comment: Ooooh, wait, I see it now: he's just defining what addition is for 0, successor ordinals, and limit ordinals, where once the paren shift takes place we understand the summation using the old definition.  Never mind, thank you, I see it now.

Comment: Exactly. Please enjoy the book! I am also studying the book now!

Comment: Many thanks, are you studying it independently or in a course?  I'm on my own and moving slow but steady--simultaneously reading Marker's Model Theory book among other projects.

Comment: Actually I'm also studying on my own. But I'm taking it not so seriously. I'm studying other areas as well, such as complex/harmonic analysis and lots of geometry. I think the blog  below will be very helpful for you in many purposes: [link](https://hamsandwichthm.wordpress.com/)